# How to get Error Message from previous connector Logic App

Tags: error-handling, azure-logic-apps

Is it possible to get and insert the previous connector's error message in a connector that gets triggered on failed after, to log the error message?

I did a seach and tested something like: `@{body('XML_Validation')['message']}`.

If so, is it also possible to get the Error code for the failed connector?

-----UPDATE-----

Ok so the previous test of `@{body('XML_Validation')['message']}` works on some connectors but not XML-Validation.

Is it still possible to extract the error message / exception somehow?

this is what i watch to get as a message to implement in another logic app:
[image]

Comment: Hi @jeffhollan :) Any ideas here? Thanks :)

Comment: Just replied on answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every action following the trigger-event can run under specific conditions. Defined like this in the code view: 
"runAfter": {
                    "PreviousAction": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                }

You could set the "runAfter" to run on "Failed" and capture the message this way.

Have a look at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-exception-handling

Comment: Well i have already handeld the exception of what happens after that specific connector fails. But i also want the message that is set on the previous failed connector (as the error message shown above) to be implemented into the action running after the one which failed. i want that error message to be passed down so to speak. i cant access that error message is what i am saying. Am i still missing the point of the answer please be so kind to tell me then. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I'll try to reproduce something, wasn't clear for me that you were already capturing the failed-result.

Comment: What are the raw outputs of the action that's failing? It's possible there is no "body" so @body('someAction') may not work. But @outputs('someAction') should

Comment: Thank you Steven.

I would say that there is no body, correct , because i don't get any output at all it seems from the failed action (in this case XML_Validation). I only get that error message as a resault of the file i'm using to be validated. Its a purposely created error btw. The aim here is to be able to someone access that error message to so that i can log it. So i tried the @outputs('XML_Validation') and that didin't work either. @jeffhollan thanks for the answer. :)

Comment: @John I figured out what your question/problem is, however no solution on that so I'll have to pingback on Jeff for this. The thing is, you're not getting an exception from the XML Validation because it failed, but you are getting an exception from the logic app runtime because input for the XML Validation connector is incorrect. Because of this, the XML_Validation does not generate an output, but just has a status failed and has the "Error"-context property set. So your question is, how do I read the "Error"-property from the connector itself,rather then from it's result or output.

Comment: Alright, think I found the syntax that you need. Try @actions('XML_Validation')['error']. This returns the error message from the action.

Comment: Thank you @StevenVanEycken ! It worked perfectly. That was exactly what i was looking for! :D

Comment: Thanks. Sounds like we could use some docs on this so will let the team know :)

Answer (score 1):

Building on Steven's comment from the accepted answer, in my case I used the following:

```
@actions('Add_registrant_to_GoToWebinar')['outputs']['statusCode']
```

It allows to get the `statusCode` from the raw output of the connector, because this connector does not expose it.